# write the output of a function to an Excel cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to write the output of a user defined function to cell in Excel

This works. It writes the value to the cell:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet.cell(row=(LastRow+1),column=2).value = random.randint(1,100)
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

But this does not. The cell remains empty:

```
def reader1():
    random.randint(1,100)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet.cell(row=(LastRow+1),column=2).value = reader1()
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

I do not receive an error message in either case.
I've tried it various ways, but cannot get it to work.
Any help would be appreciated, including feedback on the formatting of this post (my first).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your function, you need to return the value of you `random.randint` to have the column update it's value. By default a function returns `None`

```
def reader1():

     return random.randint(1,100)
```